# PHP + SQL - insert value of primary key to another field in the same row

Tags: php, sql, key, field

I need to insert a row to table where second element of the row (chatID) copies value of auto incremented primary key (messageID).

```
safe_query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."messenger ('messageID', 'chatID') VALUES('','')");
```

Any ideas would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Use a transaction, on insert get last inserted id and update, commit or use trigger on insert

Comment: you can first just insert messageID and then run second query UPDATE table set `messageID` = `chatID`

Answer (score 0):

In php when you inserted the record get the `lastInsertId();` and update the chatID

```
$inserted_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$sth2 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ".PREFIX."messenger 
SET `chatID`= $inserted_id WHERE `messageID`=$inserted_id");
$sth2->execute();
```